# Getting a total copied set of rows in VBA and storing it in a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have a fairly simple syntax question:

I'm trying to copy and paste n rows from one excel file to another. In addition, I'd like to store the total copied rows into a variable.
 Can someone help me accomplish this?

For example:

1)

```
Activate CSV file
Apply Filter to Column B (Page Title) & uncheck "blanks" ("<>") filter**
Windows("Test_Origin.xlsm").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$206").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
```

2)

```
Copy Filtered Lines with data (Excluding Row 1)
Range("B2:F189").Select
Selection.Copy
copiedRowTotal = total *FILTERED* rows copied over from original sheet, then Test Number iterates that many times
copiedRowTotal = Selection.Rows.Count
MsgBox copiedRowTotal
```

Thanks

Comment: what are you tying to store to an integer? the number of rows in the selection `Range("B2:F189").Select Selection.Copy `? Is that right?

Comment: Yes. I'd like to store that total to  copiedrowtotal so I can use it later. Thanks
!

Answer (score 2):

An indirect way to do this is

```
Range("B2:F189").Copy
Range("M2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
copiedRowTotal = Selection.Rows.Count
Selection.Clear
```

The code copies the range & does a paste special operation on a separate location.
By doing this, only filtered rows are copied to M2 & the area (where the filtered rows are pasted) is highlighted when `PasteSpecial` operation is done.

Doing a `Selection.Rows.Count` gives one, the number of filtered rows that were pasted.
After figuring out the number of filtered rows, the selection is cleared up.

Comment: keep in mind the Copy() method has the optional parameter for the destination. you can copy and paste in one line that way.
`Dim destination as String`
`Set r = Selection`
`r.Copy(destination)`
`r.Rows.Count`

Comment: @Brad: You are right. I don't know if `PasteSpecial` works that way. Thanks!!

Comment: @Dan: If this answer is what you were looking for, go ahead & accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to get the visible cell count directly.  I tried using the 'SpecialCells(xlSpecialCellsVisible)' function, but could not get the correct count with a filter applied.  Here is a quick function I wrote that works with a filter applied.

Also be aware that sometimes a filter can mess with the selected range at times, so it's something to note.

```
Public Sub TestIt()

    Dim visibleCount As Long

    visibleCount = GetVisibleCount(Sheets(1).Range("A2:H3000"))

    MsgBox visibleCount
End Sub

Public Function GetVisibleCount(rng As Range) As Long

    Dim loopRow As Range

    GetVisibleCount = 0

    For Each loopRow In rng.Rows
        If loopRow.Hidden = False Then
            GetVisibleCount = GetVisibleCount + 1
        End If
    Next loopRow
End Function
```

Comment: it is possible to count it in one line ! check out the code I have posted I just wanted you to know as it waste of time doing looping Thanks!

Comment: Never thought of using subtotal, but you would get the count of all the cells in the passed range, and not the row count, however.

Comment: I'm not sure why or how you got an incorrect reading with the specialcells function, but what the OP has described is exactly what specialcells should be used for.

Comment: @reafidy.  Can you get the specialcells function to work properly on an autofiltered range? It returned a result of 0 for me.  Maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: Hi Fink, No offence intended but I think you are definitely doing something wrong!  Using specialcells (visible) cannot return a value of zero.  Instead it throws an error "No cells were found", that's actually its downfall in my view, it would be better if it did return zero.  Yes sure I can make it work, I use it all the time. Try something like: Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count  I noticed that you said you used 'xlSpecialCellsVisible' which is incorrect it should be 'xlCellTypeVisible', maybe that was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
copiedrowtotal = selection.rows.count ' its not selection.totalcells
```

I think this would do the trick

After seeing your update let me tell you probably these would work

```
dim i as long
i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(2,worksheets("Sheet").Range("B2:F189"))
```

Now i has the number of filtered rows in it! If you have included header in your range then do -1 at the end else just leave it up

```
argument 2 in subtotal is => counting the rows and then sheet name 
and then specify range to count filtered rows
```

instead I would select only one column if you applied filter for many columns!
Hope it helps dont forget to accept an answer ! :

Comment: This is great, but I forgot to specify what I'm trying to do. I'd like to actually grab the total number of filtered rows.  I'll update my original question so you can see.