# Getting a total copied set of rows in VBA and storing it in a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I asked this question a bit ago, but asked it incorrectly, and wasn't able to receive the best answer.

I have a fairly simple syntax question:

I'm trying to copy and paste n rows from one excel file to another. In addition, I'd like to store the total **FILTERED** copied rows into a variable. Can someone help me accomplish this?

For example:

***'1) Activate CSV file, Apply Filter to Column B (Page Title) & uncheck "blanks" ("<>") filter***

Windows("Test_Origin.xlsm").Activate

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$206").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"

***'2) Copy Filtered Lines with data (Excluding Row 1)***

Range("B2:F189").Select

Selection.Copy

copiedRowTotal = Selection.Rows.Count **<-- This doesn't give me the FILTERED rows**

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a total copied set of rows in VBA and storing it in a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420657/getting-a-total-copied-set-of-rows-in-vba-and-storing-it-in-a-variable)

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once. If you want to modify your original question, then click `edit` instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
dim i as long
i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(2,worksheets("Sheet").Range("B2:F189"))
```

Gave you the description here
[Getting a total copied set of rows in VBA and storing it in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420657/getting-a-total-copied-set-of-rows-in-vba-and-storing-it-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
copiedRowTotal  = Range("B2:B189").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
```

Comment: well its all becauase of you guys i learnt lot of stuff from stackoverflow thanks for all of you! im just learning from you guys! and yes i want to tell you that specialcells(xlcelltypevisible).count isnt working i have tested thats why i posted other solution . did you check it reafidy ?

Comment: Good stuff! Try it again if you don't mind, I incorrectly used the wrong range. It should definitely work, I use it like this all the time, its what it was made for. :)

Comment: By the way another excellent resource for excel/vba is www.ozgrid.com/forum pop in and say hello sometime.